# XsltListViewWebPart View BaseViewID

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, client-side

I'm making a sharepoint hosted app and created a list with several views.

Is it possible to show a specific view on a page ?

Like i have a view with `View BaseViewID="2"` and want to show only this view in a webpart.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible to achieve using a module and provision XlstListViewWebPart. In my last blog post (http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/28/SharePoint-Apps-for-Public-Site--XsltListView-Web-Part-approach) I've shared how to do it even for anonymous users. You can check code here - http://spsitepro.codeplex.com/.